# Doing a group by ordered by date

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm getting latest unread messages for a user ordered by date:

```
$messages = Message::whereReceiver(Auth::user()->id)->whereRead(0)->orderBy('sent', 'desc')->get();
```

and the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [suggest_id] => 5
            [content] => How are you?
            [receiver] => 1
            [sent] => 2014-02-05 18:50:37
            [read] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [suggest_id] => 5
            [content] => Hi
            [receiver] => 1
            [sent] => 2014-02-05 18:09:15
            [read] => 0
        )
)
```

But when I do a `groupBy` results won't be descending any more:

```
$messages = Message::whereReceiver(Auth::user()->id)->whereRead(0)->orderBy('sent', 'desc')->groupBy('suggest_id')->get();
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [suggest_id] => 5
            [content] => Hi
            [receiver] => 1
            [sent] => 2014-02-05 18:09:15
            [read] => 0
        )
)
```

However I expect the message with date of `2014-02-05 18:50:37` be the output!

Answer (score 0):

This could be an alternative (if you want to get only one/first message)

```
Message::whereReceiver(Auth::user()->id)
       ->whereRead(0)
       ->orderBy('sent', 'desc')
       ->take(1) // Just get the top/first one from the set, ordered by desc
       ->get();
```

If you want to get all the unread messages then it's (you have it already)

```
Message::whereReceiver(Auth::user()->id)
       ->whereRead(0)
       ->orderBy('sent', 'desc')
       ->get();
```

Comment: That will show only one message, if you notice `suggest_id` a user can have more than one new message on every suggest. so I need grouping based on it.

Comment: Then remove the grouping, there would be only one message at the same time.

Comment: No there can be more than one unread messages. At that way all unread messages will be displayed. I need the newest message per suggest.

Comment: Then what do you want, all unread messages should be fetched from DB or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Its is a "problem" with SQL.

translating this query to SQL query will be:

```
select * from messages where read = 0 group by suggest_id order by sent desc
```

by default mysql will group the rows and get the first to show. To show the last row in a group in mysql:

```
select * from ( select * from messages where read = 0 order by sent desc ) as messages group by suggested_id
```

You can do that with Eloquent but is not a good idea, If you want to improove this, you can create a view and set up a event to update each hour this view.

To do the query above with eloquent you can do this:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from ( select * from messages where read = ? order by sent desc ) as messages group by suggested_id', array(1));
```